# Kotlin - Why do we have to explicit type parameter(s) for generic method?

Tags: kotlin

I'm working on extension method like this:

```
infix fun <T> T.isNullOr(other: T): Boolean {
    if (this == null) return true
    return this == other
}
```

and I'm trying to use this method like this.

```
val thisShouldWork = true isNullOr true // this is true
val thisShouldNotWork = true isNullOr 0 // No compilation errors?
```

I expected compilation error because type parameter is automatically set to `Boolean` for `isNullOr`  but it wasn't. What's happening?

am I misunderstanding about it?

in C#, same code working well as I expected.

```cs
static bool IsNullOr<T>(this T t, T other) {
    if (t == null) return true;
    return Equals(t, other);
}

bool howAboutThis = 0.IsNullOr(0);
bool andThis = 0.IsNullOr(false); // error - cannot detect type parameter for this
```

Comment: what happens when you replace `true` with a variable that is true?
`val thisShouldNotWork = someVarThatIsTrue isNullOr 0`

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert well, it returns `false`. But I expected compilation error because types are not the same. (`Boolean` and `Int`..)

Comment: Forcing `infix fun <T : Boolean> T.isNullOr(other: T): Boolean {` makes the compiler give an error, but it seems like a bug otherwise

Comment: Maybe it thinks `T` is `Object`?

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert Thanks for comment. but this is extension method, so I planned to use it globally. Forcing types will restrict uses of this extension method and I have to make another methods If I want to use it for another type.

(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: @dyukha's comment makes sense, if you're sending in two different types, maybe `T` is seen as `Any` and not Boolean.

Comment: @dyukha You're right, but I wonder why it does not restrict `T` to `Boolean` or something. If I use `Object() isNullOr 0` then, I have nothing to say but it isn't.

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert exactly, I'm facing the problem what you said.

Comment: In C#, `int` doesn't extend `object`; in Kotlin, `Int` does extend `Any`.

Comment: In addition, would you like this to fail: `mutableListOf(1).isNullOr(listOf(1))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remember that generic type information is erased at runtime and whenever you try to put something into a method that accepts generics, then the common denominator is assumed, e.g.:

```
listOf("one", 123) // -> assumes T:Any and therefore gives List<Any>
```

Now for your example that would mean `"one".isNullOr(123)` both become `Any`.

As a sidenote however, if you declare a specific type (e.g. `List<String>`) as shown next, it will not work to assign a different type to it:

```
val test : List<String> = listOf(123) // this will not work
```

It is already known at compile time that the given int can't become a string. This sample however doesn't help you as you do not return that generic type. If your method just looked a bit different, e.g. would have a generic type as return value, it might easily have worked out similar to the `List`-sample before.

So to fix your sample you need to specify the type which will basically make the `infix` obsolete, e.g. the following will work as you expect:

```
val someString : String? = TODO()
val works = someString.isNullOr<String?>("other")
val doesntWork = someString.isNullOr<Int?>(123) // does not nor does:
val doesntWorkToo = someString.isNullOr<String?>(123)
```

Note that for what you've shown some standard functionality might help you (but not eliminate that specific problem), i.e. using the [`?:` (elvis operator)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) with a `?.let`:

```
val someVal : String? = "someString given from somewhere"
val thisWorks = someVal?.let { 
                     it == "some other string to compare" 
                } ?: true /* which basically means it was null */
val thisWillNot = someVal?.let {
                     it == 123 // compile error (funny enough: it.equals(123) would work ;-)
                  } ?: true /* it is null */
```

Comment: Well, I used `if (someClass?.isValid ?: false)` code, but Android Studio gives me a hint that can be used without elvis operator. So I tried for it but it does not work what I expected.

Comment: I think the suggestion means to use something like the following: `if (someClass?.isValid == true)`... this way the `false` is not really needed, as `null != true` and therefore gives `false` too... but I think that suggestion isn't the best one ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Here, `val thisShouldNotWork = true isNullOr 0` is equal to `val thisShouldNotWork: Boolean = true.isNullOr<Any>(0)`. Type parameter as inferred as the closest parent.

And function's return type is based on **logical expression evaluation**: `this == other`. Let's see `==` function declaration: `public open operator fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean`. It receives `Any?`.

Type parameter in this function has nothing to do with `Boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case the generics don't really matter. You only call `equals` in the method, which you can do on any type. It's basically the same as:

```
infix fun Any.isNullOr(other: Any): Boolean {
    return this == other
}
```

It compiles without problems because you can always call `equals` with anything: `other: Any?`

Answer (score 0):

Thank for answers. I think there is no way to prevent this at compilation level, so I decided to check type for `other`.

```
inline infix fun <reified T> T.isNullOr(other: T): Boolean {
    if (this == null) return true
    if (other !is T) return false
    return this == other
}
```

Comment: this will not work out as you might think... the `other !is T` will never be true... just try it out... you could place something like `return false.apply { println("am i called?") }` there to test it...

Comment: @Roland well, it does. Every Kotlin types inherit Any, so it does not happened?
I can't check it's *derived type* (like `Int`, `Boolean`) not the *super type* ?

Comment: I mean, `Int` should be type checked as `Int` not `Any`. In this context, `Int` will be *derived type* and `Any` will be `super type` . sorry for my bad explanation :S

Comment: Ok... "should"...But don't forget the part where generic type information is erased at runtime.. that specific `other !=is T` has not the effect you think it has... try adding `.apply { println("<condition named>") }` to each of the returned values and you will see it...

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to prevent it, you can:

```
class IsNullOr<T>(val x: T) {
    operator fun invoke(other: T): Boolean {        
        if (x == null) return true
        return x == other
    }
}

fun <T> T.isNullOr() = IsNullOr(this)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val thisShouldWork = true.isNullOr()(true) // compiles
    val thisShouldNotWork = true.isNullOr()(0) // doesn't compile
}
```

This makes type inference depend only on the receiver of `isNullOr`. If `val`s could be generic, you'd even keep the original syntax (but they can't).